# Jumping element during width animation

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to animate width on my fixed element using `calc` simply because I can't make it relative. It's one of those nav bars that hide when scrolling down and appear back on the top when scrolling up.

For some reason the animation isn't smooth and the 'Settings' div jumps between the transitions. The weird or maybe not that weird bit is that it works fine in Chrome but not in IE...

I know having a div with a calculated width isn't the best idea here but I simply can't make it relative due to its constant disappearance on scroll. I have spent hours trying to figure it out for nothing. Try running it in IE and compare it with Chrome.

```js
const sideMenu = document.querySelector('.side-menu');

sideMenu.addEventListener('click', function() {
  sideMenu.classList.toggle('collapse');
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.side-menu {
  width: 160px;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #ccc;
  transition: ease-in-out 0.3s;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.side-menu.collapse {
  width: 50px;
}

.side-menu.collapse + .right-panel > .top {
  width: calc(100% - 50px);
}

.right-panel {
  position: relative;
  background-color: yellow;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.top {
  position: fixed;
  height: 70px;
  width: calc(100% - 160px);
  background-color: #c3c3c3;
  transition: ease-in-out 0.3s;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.banner {
  width: calc(100% - 20vw);
}

.settings {
  width: 20vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="side-menu">Click</div>

<div class="right-panel">
  <div class="top">
    <div class="banner">Banner</div>
    <div class="settings">Settings</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain why IE has those stuttering issues, but you can simplify your layout to not use `calc`, which appears to solve the problem.

As you're using `fixed` and want to cover the full width of the page, instead of the `calc()` you can use `left` and `right`.

E.g. In `.top` we change `calc(100% - 160px);` this to

```
right: 0;
left: 160px;
```

And in `.side-menu.collapse + .right-panel > .top`

`width: calc(100% - 50px);` becomes `left: 50px;`

```js
const sideMenu = document.querySelector('.side-menu');

sideMenu.addEventListener('click', function() {
  sideMenu.classList.toggle('collapse');
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.side-menu {
  width: 160px;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #ccc;
  transition: ease-in-out 0.3s;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.side-menu.collapse {
  width: 50px;
}

.side-menu.collapse + .right-panel > .top {
  left: 50px;
}

.right-panel {
  position: relative;
  background-color: yellow;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.top {
  position: fixed;
  height: 70px;
  right: 0;
  left: 160px;
  background-color: #c3c3c3;
  transition: ease-in-out 0.3s;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.banner {
  width: calc(100% - 20vw);
}

.settings {
  width: 20vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="side-menu">Click</div>

<div class="right-panel">
  <div class="top">
    <div class="banner">Banner</div>
    <div class="settings">Settings</div>
  </div>
</div>
```